# Android - Resizing map when keyboard is raised stops working after calling setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-windowmanager

I'm having problems with the keyboard no longer adjusting my maps size when it's raised / lowered.

I have a layout that has an EditText to collect an email address, and then a framelayout holding a MapFragment below it.  I'm using the Maps API v2

I was using `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation` and in the MapFragment's onCreate I called the below so that the keyboard would shrink the map as it raised/lowered up which worked.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

I realized I needed to potentially be getting the current location in case the last known location was old or unavailable so I set `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)` and set up it's listener.

The weird thing is, once I enable this, the map no longer shrinks when I raise the keyboard, it covers it up instead.  I tried setting this to true, getting the location, and disabling it and it still wouldn't shrink correctly.  I've also tried setting the window parameters after I enable myLocation.

Update - With further testing, I also found that if I rotate the device into landscape, and then back into portrait, the keyboard will adjust the map correctly.

Why would enabling your current location override the window settings set earlier? Is there some other way to try and force it after I set `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`   I don't really want to apply it to the whole activity as this is just one of many fragments.